# Unable to open Firefox on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: firefox, mir, 18.04

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 Development Branch. Suddenly today Firefox stopped working.

```
royal:~$ firefox
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

I am getting above error if I try opening it from terminal. I have Firefox 59 installed via snap package.

I have already tried,

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

But, it didn't help. Please help soon. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Development branches **often** break.  What have you recently updated?  File a bug against the relevant package.

Comment: I had installed gparted yesterday. Thats it. I tried apt version of firefox, thats working. Snap one is not working.

Comment: @sudodus: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question (to answer)? If you tack hardly related questions onto existing questions you broaden their scope which makes them harder to answer. I took the liberty to revert the edit that adds the follow-up question. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, I simply wanted to make this question useful for other users (who might want to get involved in testing the development version) instead of closing it. I accept, that it not the way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you want to help develop and debug the latest and greatest Ubuntu

I suggest that you use the 'apt version of Firefox' until the bug with the snap version is fixed. Things like this should  be expected in the developing version.

Please help by reporting bugs at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) and the [ISO testing tracker](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/) :-)

You can also discuss the developing version at [this Ubuntu Forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=427).

### If you want a smooth ride

As a matter of fact, if you want a smooth ride, you should wait until July or August (2018) until Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, the first point release is available.

My experience from previous versions with long time support, LTS, is that the first point release is debugged and polished.

Comment: Thanks. I would love to find issues and have reported also few. Thats why I installed 18.04 at this moment of time. I was fully unaware of Mir server part, thats why I asked this query. BTW Thanks for those bug tracking list and forum links. :)

Comment: @OmkarNathSingh, You are very welcome :-)